# Command failed when redirection failed

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm running java program with bat script using command line:

```
start "AppName" /B %LOCAL_JAVA% -jar Starter.jar %* 1>out.txt 2>err.txt
```

I want to run bat script for a second time, java application will connect using TCP socket to first running and will pass script args. But instead of this I get error:

```
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

This is because files out.txt and err.txt are used by first running application.

How I can ignore failed stream redirection and run my command line?

Comment: You have to use different log files for each running instance of the program.

Answer (score 0):

start "AppName" /B %LOCAL_JAVA% -jar Starter.jar %* 1>%random%out.txt 2>%random%err.txt

like that? what do you mean it runs twice? does the command run twice or the program?

Comment: If program is run twice, second instance is sending params to first instance (args from command line). I don't want to use random file names, it will cause mess in program directory :(